# Calculate joint Distribution function (X,Y), when X~Unif(0,1), Y=X

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I am new to this topic right now. This is how I proceeded-

$\int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{x} 1 dy dx$ = ${x^2}\over{2}$

Also, we were supposed to calculate its mixed partials?

For that $\partial^2{{x^2}\over{2}}\over\partial{x}\partial{y}$ = 1 for x between [0,1].

I don't know if I am proceeding right or not. Is my solution correct?

Comment: I would suggest starting by finding the joint CDF. Remember that $F_{X,Y} (x, y) = P(X\leq x, Y\leq y)$

Comment: Oh so, $\int_{0}^{y}\int_{0}^{x} 1 dv du$ = xy? As Y=X, so X<x,Y<y => x<y. So first integrating from 0 to x and then 0 to y?

Comment: Either you are provided with the joint density of $(X,Y)$, or $X$ and $Y$ are independent. If it is the latter, then $Y=X$ in distribution.

Comment: yes. Y is equal to X.  If they only had the same distribution then I think it would have been mentioned as Y~Unif(0,1). I think Y=X means Y takes value x

Comment: It's fine, but your calculation suggested otherwise. See the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

If $z_1$ or $z_2$ are negative, then $Pr(X \le z_1, Y \le z_2)=0$.

Let $z_1, z_2 $ are positive, then

\begin{align}
Pr(X \le z_1, Y \le z_2) &= Pr(X \le \min(z_1, z_2))\\
&= \min(z_1, z_2,1)
\end{align}

Comment: Nice. I understood it. Although, this example was given to practice the double integral form of joint density, if not much inconvenience, can you please provide a solution with that method?

Comment: @AvinashBhawnani $(X,X)$ does not have a joint density.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? My groundwork is a bit shaky it seems like

Comment: hmmm... if the intention is for you to practice integration of joint density, then perhaps the intention is to say that $X$ and $Y$ are independent and they need not be equal. In general, joint density function need not exists. That is in general, we need not be able to find a function such that integrating it gives us the CDF. CDF always exists, but a density function need not exists. Not every function is differentiable

Comment: My bad my bad! I meant to say, double integral to find out joint distribution! I wrote density, really sorry.